# Get parent's index() value of the child

Tags: javascript, jquery, gallery, selector, indexing

How do I get the **parent** element's index value in relation to the **document**, of the clicked **child**, `$(this)`, element?

### HTML

```
<html>
   <body>
      <header>
         <div class="gallery">
            <div class="controls">
               <button class="next"></button>
               <button class="previous"></button>
            </div>
         </div>
      </header>
      <section>
         <section>
            <article>
               <div class="gallery">
                  <div class="controls">
                     <button class="next"></button>
                     <button class="previous"></button>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="gallery">
                  <div class="controls">
                     <button class="next"></button>
                     <button class="previous"></button>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </article>
         </section>
      </section>
   </body>
</html>
```

In this HTML it is possible to declare a gallery at any place you like within the body. So I need an “intelligent” selector to solve the problem.

### Pseudo JavaScript

```
$('.controls button').click(function() {
   var hope = $(this).parents('.gallery').index();
   alert(hope);
}
```

### **Expected** output

**Scenario**
Click on a button of the **second** gallery in this **document**:

```
1
```

Comment: Why doesn't your HTML have closing tags?

Comment: I thought it would be easier to read.

Comment: It's not easier to read without closing tags, you should include them.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: @MohammadAdil I have created a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mBmyL/).

Comment: Thank you, you both solved the problem. Now I've got another question: Which answer should I accept? :)

Comment: I was first, and made a working example..? ;p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.gallery').index( $(this).parents('.gallery') );
```

`.index()` is finding the index of the passed element in the group of elements that it is applied to.

Take a look at my [working jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/mBmyL/).

**source(s)**

[jQuery API - .index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

Answer (score 4):

When you call index(), it gives you the position relative to the collection of elements you have selected, in this case,

```
$(this).parents('.gallery')
```

Instead, you want it relative to the galleries in the entire document, so you need:

```
$('.gallery').index($(this).parents('.gallery'))
```